# how to convert table to pdf in angular 7/8/9/10?

Tags: angular

I have searched far and wide and found many solutions that work on jsPDF.But the solutions I found either try to add lines of text manually, which is impossible in my scenario; or they convert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first install jspdf library

> "npm install jspdf --save"

jspdf@2.3.1 work for me.

then after import jspdf in component and create function for export

import { jsPDF } from 'jspdf';

```
      generatePdf() {
            var head = [['NAME', 'DATE', 'TIME']];
            var table_data = [];
    
            array.forEach((element: any) => {
            var item = [element.Title, element.Date, element.Time];
            table_data.push(item);
            });
    
            var doc = new jsPDF();
    
            doc.setFontSize(18);
            doc.text('Page', 11, 8);
            doc.setFontSize(11);
            doc.setTextColor(100);
            (doc as any).autoTable({
            head: head,
            body: table_data,
            theme: 'striped',
            didDrawCell: data => {
                // data
            }
            })
    
            var data64 = doc.output('datauristring');
    
            // create pdf file and download it
            let a = document.createElement("a");
            a.href = data64;
            a.download = "myearning.pdf"
            a.click();
    
        }
```